.Net Maui and EntityFrameworkCoreSql Convert Color Type
I am trying to make a .NET Maui app where I have a model class with a property of type Maui.Graphics.Color:
public class Car
{      
    public string CarName{ get; set;}
    public Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color CarColor {  get; set; }      
}

I want to be able to store that property in a SQLite database.
I have been trying to write a ConverterClass with the help of ChatGpt:
class MauiColorConverter : ValueConverter<Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color, string>
{
    public MauiColorConverter(): base
        ( v=> v.ToHex(),
        v => Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb(v)
        )
    {
    }
}

In my DbContext, I am trying to use Fluent Api to convert between the Maui color type and something SQLite can understand, but I have huge problems to understand how to do it. I am rather new to both Maui and Entity Framework.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{       
    var mauiColorConverter = new MauiColorConverter();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
                .Property(t => t.CarColor)
                .HasConversion(mauiColorConverter);   
}

When I try to migrate the database, I get this error.

Startup project 'CarCreatorMaui' targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this platform. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-pmc-tfms for more information.

My question is: how can I make it so I can store and retrieve the CarColor from my Sqlite database ?

Which line of code is causing this problem? Could you please post the more code snippets so that we can help you better?
